# How to float divs with small height around one div with height large

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i solve this problem with CSS of floating DIV like in photo:

[image]

In my case, DIV-s after red DIV doesn't float arount it.

I have created divs in this form:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the left and right side in seperate `div` Tags, like this:

*Edit*: Updated Example for updated Question. You might need to watch the Stack Snippet in Fullscreen.

*Edit 2: I was wondering, why it was working on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/6z4orL6b/), but not as Stack Snippet, so instead of changing my Snippet to some kind of workadround, I decided not to change anything here. Instead, I will explain, why this happens. On JSFiddle the Custom CSS below gets applied AFTER the CSS from Bootstrap, and since it is called **Cascading** Stylesheet, the custom styles are overwritten by Bootstrap.
At jsfidlle on the other hand, the Bootstrap CSS gets applied first, so the custom lines overwrite the bootstrap CSS in this case, and it works.

If someone could explain to me in the comments, why the bootstrap `float: left` statement does not work, but the custom `float: left;` actually does, it would be great!

```css
.blue {
   border: 10px solid #fff;
   background: blue;
   height: 150px;
   float: left;
}

.red {
   border: 10px solid #fff;
   background: red;
   height: 300px;
   float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .red, .blue {
      float: none;
   }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="outer">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 blue">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 blue">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 blue">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 red">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6 blue">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but they are created by default in one parent div, and i like to float child div-s like in photo

Comment: I updated my answer after you updated your question, please take a look if this is the desired result :) Edit: It does work on jsfiddle, but not as StackS nippet. Working on it (https://jsfiddle.net/we9jcd8c/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use in the style css the parameter:

```
<div style="float: inside"></div>
```

You can put in the `float:` any of the parameters suits better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Html

```
<div class="outer">
<div c3ass="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="background-color:red;height:100px;border:1px solid black;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="background-color:red;height:100px;border:1px solid black;">
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color:red;height:100px;border:1px solid black;">

</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"style="background-color:red;height:100px;border:1px solid black;" >

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color:pink;height:200px;border:1px solid black;">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
```